# Removing a sublayer from the layer tree

Tags: ios, uikit, core-animation

I have a layer that I wish to fade out implicitly:

```
[CATransaction setValue:[NSNumber numberWithFloat:4.0f] forKey:kCATransactionAnimationDuration];
layer.hidden = YES;
```

From a memory point of view, however, I understand that `layer` still exists in the layer tree even after I have faded it out. Although this might seem like a silly question, I am interested in your thoughts on this: how should one remove `layer` from the layer tree? Do we need to?

Assuming that it needs to be removed: it seems that if I remove the layer from the super layer immediately after writing `layer.hidden = YES;`, the sublayer is removed immediately and no time is given for the control to have a fade out effect. I observe the same thing even when I place `removeFromSuperlayer` in a CATransaction completion block.